# Get Azure Webjob History - 403 Token invalid

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to retrieve the web job history of an Azure web job via REST using a .NET backend and the OAuth2 credentials flow (as described here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/get-triggered-web-job-history-slot)

How do I need to authenticate correctly?

I retrieve the token as follows:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{MySubscription}/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id={MyApp}
&grant_type=client_credentials
&scope=https://management.azure.com/.default
&client_secret={myclient_secret}
```

I get a token back, however I get a 403 error message when I try to retrieve the resource:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{MySubscription}/resourceGroups/{MyResource}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{MyApp}/slots/{MySlot}/triggeredwebjobs/{MyWebjob}/history?api-version=2021-02-01
Authorization: Bearer {MyToken}
```

> Client '{MyApp}' with object ID '{MyApp}' is not
> authorized to perform the action
> 'Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/triggeredwebjobs/history/read' using the
> scope
> '/subscriptions/{MySubscription}/resourceGroups/{MyResource}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{MyApp}/slots/{MySlot}/triggeredwebjobs/{MyWebjob}'
> or the scope is invalid. If access was granted recently, please update
> your credentials.

What am I doing wrong?

I already added the API-Permission
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't find a solution that worked with OAuth2 and the Credentials flow, I got it working with Basic Authentication. The username (userName) and password (userPWD) can be taken from the publishing profile of the respective app service.

```
GET https://{appservicename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/{jobName}/history
Authorization Basic ....
```

Answer (score 0):

The **"403 Token invalid"** error usually occurs if you missed giving permissions to particular scope (Azure Service Management).

By *giving this scope* it enables you to access `https://management.azure.com`

**To resolve this error, please follow below steps:**

***Go to Azure Ad ->your application -> API permissions -> Add permission -> Azure Service Management -> delegated permissions ->User impersonation -> Add***

[image]

After giving these permissions try to retrieve the resource again, there won't be any error.

Comment: i already added this Permission (see my Posting above), but it still doesn't work.